# If I dont want to stop a service in android after a button click,but after a certain block of code...how does one one do it?

Tags: android

```
public class Thread2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
            Log.d("TAG","into Thread2 runnable");
            Intent in=new Intent(MyService.this,Display.class);     
            in.putExtra("Integer", 1234);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(in);
        }
```

before sending the static data into the intent, service needs to be stopped...how to do it??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: was trying to run 4 threads in a service and wanted to stop service after the task was completed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service has a method

stopSelf();

Comment: thanks a lot guys...i did not pay attention to the on destroy toast that appeared..i had used stopself()..anyways thanks for the help...By the way for Emil...i was trying to run 4 threads in a service..

Answer (score 1):

You can stop a service in an activity using :

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Comment: thanks a lot..but this would work only on a button click in an activity..the "this" scope would not be allowed or work in a service..so i guess stopself() is the only option..